# MediaElement issue with Firefox, Safari

Tags: jquery, dojo, mediaelement

I am running into an issue trying to use MediaElement on a site that uses both dojo (primary JS framework) and jquery (added specifically to enable MediaElement).

The following line of code:

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({plugins:['flash'],pluginPath:'/app/public/js/mediaelement/'});
```

... is causing some sort of script loop in Firefox. The alert specifically points to line 3895 in jquery.js. The problem goes away when the above line is commented out.

Comment: As a side note... if your media is in flash, why don't you just use the dojox.av (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/av/widget.html) widgets ?

Answer (score 1):

If you hide any element of the player with CSS, e.g. `display:none;` then you will get an unresponsive script error in Firefox. Make sure you are not hiding any player elements, and use the `features` option to set the controls you need.

Example code:

```
$("audio").mediaelementplayer( {
     plugins: ['flash']
   , pluginPath: '/app/packages/mediaelement-2.6.5/build/'
   , flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf'
   , features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration']
 });
```